# Protecting webresource in tomcat 8.5 with CLIENT-CERT

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, tomcat8

I am new to tomcat, I have coded few webservices using Spring framework using tomcat 8.5. I want to protect particular webresource with auth type CLIENT-CERT. I have configured server.xml as

```
        <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
        keystoreFile="<path>/TestServerp12.pfx"
        truststoreFile="<path>/truststore.jks"
        truststorePass="****"
        keystoreType="PKCS12"
        truststoreType="JKS"
        keystorePass="******" />
```

added below in web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>App</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/authenticate/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>cert</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <login-config>
            <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
        </login-config>
```

I have followed few blogs like https://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/mutual-authentication-with-client-cert-tomcat-6-and-httpclient/ and stackoverflow question on it.

With above config, protected URL throws 403 so I have to add security role in web.xml

```
    <security-role>
            <role-name>cert</role-name>
        </security-role>

    and below in tomcat users

    <role rolename="cert"/>
        <user username="EMAILADDRESS=testclient3@email.com, CN=TestClient3, OU=Test, O=MyO, L=TestL, ST=TestST, C=LA" password="null" roles="cert"/>
```

After adding this it SSL handshake is successful but user name (Distinguish Name of client cert) is hardcoded which essentially means that other users will not have access to it.

What is way to enable CLIENT-CERT auth in tomcat without hardcoding users ?

Comment: You need a legitimate user database and not the flat-file thing that you have configured. What do you have available for an authentication database? Or are you starting from scratch?

Comment: I'm starting from scratch, I have followed http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html to configure SSL in tomcat. I have client cert which is installed on machine and when I hit protected webservice then browser prompts for client cert. In tomcat logs I can see successful SSL handshake

Comment: How would you like to store the identities of valid users? In a relational database? In LDAP? It's clear you don't want to use a flat-file... so what do you want to use instead? Tomcat can use many back-end stores for authorization information.

Comment: Well, keystore and truststore will take care of it since client issued certs will have same CA. Anyways I found solution for this https://github.com/Unicon/x509authentication-bypassing-tomcat-realm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without any external utilities. It just wasn't clear from your question exactly what you were trying to do. What you really wanted to do was treat all users as if they were in one single group without having to explicitly-place every user into that role (e.g. with a user database).

This can be done using Tomcat's `allRolesMode` which you can read about in the [Realm section of the Tomcat users guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/realm.html#UserDatabase_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm).

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
    allRolesMode="authOnly"
    resourceName="UserDatabase" />
```

Now in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`, you will set the `<security-constraint>` to require "any role":

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>My Secure Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This technique works in all currently-supported versions of Apache Tomcat (6.0 - 9.0).